# asking questions that might not have a good answer

Tags: discussion, questions

before asking a question I do some research and try to find the solution myself, after a good amount of research and effort time put into it I would go on SO and ask the question.

The thing is, what if the possible answer to my question is "this is not possible" or "no you can't do this" or "even with the latest framework version you can't do it", How should we handle this kind of questions?

Comment: If they are otherwise on-topic, they're fine.  Sometimes a "that's impossible" answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's the answer then that's the answer. If you *think* that this may be the case when writing the question, then do everything you can to still get a workable solution out of it. Namely: provide enough context information about what you're trying to achieve so that alternative solutions may be provided. If you just ask *how to do X with Y* and the answer is *you don't*, then that's that.

But if you ask:

> I want to foo the bar and my current approach is to do X with Y, which fails because of [insert error here].

then the answer can be:

> X'ing the Y doesn't work, but you could Z the bar directly.

Also see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/476).

Comment: but, what if the answer doesn't really satisfy want you wanted, should you accept it as an answer and mark it or should you keep waiting for another answer?

Comment: Nobody's forcing you to accept anything; if the answer doesn't help then don't. If it's clear from the answer that there's not going to be a more satisfactory answer to the question in its current form, then that *is* your answer and you may as well accept it. If you think there *is* a better answer, then you should wait and promote the question in some way to draw attention to it.